# Change value in remember when property change in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a code:

```
@Composable
fun TypeRadioGroup(
    type: Type,
    onTypeChange: (type: Type) -> Unit
) {
    val options = listOf(Type.Oney, Type.Round)

    var selectedOption by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(type)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(type) {
        selectedOption = type
    }

    val cornerRadius = 4.dp
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        options.forEachIndexed { index, type ->
            OutlinedButton(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .offset(x = if (index == 0) 0.dp else (-1).dp),
                onClick = {
                    selectedOption = options[index]
                    onTypeChange(selectedOption)
                },
                shape = when (index) {
                    //this is for future multi trip option
                    0 -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = cornerRadius, topEnd = 0.dp, bottomStart = cornerRadius, bottomEnd = 0.dp)
                    options.size - 1 -> RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 0.dp,
                        topEnd = cornerRadius,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                    )

                    else -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 0.dp, topEnd = 0.dp, bottomStart = 0.dp, bottomEnd = 0.dp)
                },
                border = BorderStroke(1.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled)),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
                    backgroundColor = if (selectedOption == flightType) DesignSystemColors.Primary05 else DesignSystemColors.White
                ),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "TEXT",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now sometimes when type was changed I got new type, but in LaunchedEffect selectedOption is still the same as last, even if type is different. Any ideas how change selectedOptions every time when type is changed?

Comment: is there any reason to use LaunchedEffect?

Comment: no, without LaunchedEffect still not working properly. I only tested that solution

Comment: rememeberSavable accpet key as well, so you can pass the data as key on which you want to execute the block when that get changed. Have you tried that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think should work to select an option.

```
@Composable
fun TypeRadioGroup(
    selectedType: Type, // changed the param name because of name shadowing
    onTypeChange: (type: Type) -> Unit
) {
    val options = listOf(Type.Oney, Type.Round)

    val cornerRadius = 4.dp
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        options.forEachIndexed { index, type ->
            OutlinedButton(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .offset(x = if (index == 0) 0.dp else (-1).dp),
                onClick = { onTypeChange(type) },
                shape = when (index) {
                    //this is for future multi trip option
                    0 -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = cornerRadius, topEnd = 0.dp, bottomStart = cornerRadius, bottomEnd = 0.dp)
                    options.size - 1 -> RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 0.dp,
                        topEnd = cornerRadius,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                    )

                    else -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 0.dp, topEnd = 0.dp, bottomStart = 0.dp, bottomEnd = 0.dp)
                },
                border = BorderStroke(
                    1.dp,
                   color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
                ),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
                   backgroundColor = if (selectedType == flightType) DesignSystemColors.Primary05 else DesignSystemColors.White
                ),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "TEXT",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the state is hoisted, you need to provide it and on change event to the composable function like this.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun TypeRadioGroupPreview() {
    YourAppsTheme {
        var selectedType by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(Type.Oney) }
        TypeRadioGroup(selectedType = selectedType, onTypeChange = { selectedType = it })
    }
}
```